# Changing base URL for ASP HyperLinkColumn

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a simple code to list files with `DataGrid`. It's the server side code:

```
Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~\images\"))
articleList.DataSource = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*")
articleList.DataBind()
```

.ASPX page tag:

```
    <asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="articleList" Font-Name="Verdana"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#eeeeee"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="Navy" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        HeaderStyle-Font-Size="15pt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True">
      <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name" 
               HeaderText="File Name" Target="_blank"/>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Last Write Time"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Length" HeaderText="File Size"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
            DataFormatString="{0:#,### bytes}" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

It lists files in `http://localhost/images` but **.aspx** file location is `http://localhost/cp/list.aspx` then hyperlinks location is something like this: `http://localhost/cp/myfile.jpg` since the file location is `http://localhost/images/myfile.jpg` .
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [DataNavigateUrlFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx)

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name"  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://localhost/images/{0}" HeaderText="File Name" Target="_blank"/>
```

Here `{0}` will be your image name i.e. `Name` column  Value.